# Getting status when launching an alias in bash

Tags: bash

I've figured out how to use aliases from within a bash script. They do get executed, but I don't get the result back in the variable "Status". All following types of launching an alias get the result back when used interactively, but "Status" stay empty in the script no matter if I use "shopt -s expand_aliases" or not:

```
$ Status=`start_ETAP-TestCluster 2>/dev/null`
$ echo $Status
{"JobIds":["8c54392c-363c-4e28-827e-a1384da7fd37"]}

$ Status=`${BASH_ALIASES[start_NetIntel-Cluster]} 2>/dev/null`
$ echo $Status
{"JobIds":["dd05f5cb-a490-4fe3-b4fd-be61f62bbb88"]}

$ eval Status=`${BASH_ALIASES[start_NetIntel-Cluster]} 2>/dev/null`
$ echo $Status
{JobIds:[25a246ab-e5f5-4d65-80ea-4ff5e15cc02c]}

$ eval $(echo Status=`${BASH_ALIASES[start_NetIntel-Cluster]} 2>/dev/null`)
$ echo $Status
{JobIds:[4ce2f4e5-0599-47f5-b7f4-cd2ec1de9909]}
```

Has anyone some hints and ideas how to get the result in the variable "Status" within a bash script ?

Comment: Why is this tagged with java, python, r, and scala?

Comment: Do you want to get exit status of the command any_var=``start_ETAP-TestCluster 2>/dev/null``? If yes then you can use status=$?  after your command.

Answer (score 1):

The command between back quotes, or betwen `$(` and `)` is expanded by the shell to the ouput of command. The exit status can be retrieved with $? special variable.

```
output=$(command )    #  output=`command `  #old syntax
status=$?
```

Otherwise standard output and error can be redirected to files.

```
command 1> output_file 2> error_file
status=$?
```

Also if only the exit status success is wanted the status can be checked with logical operators (exit status ==0 means success and logical value true)

```
command 1> output_file 2> error_file || {
    echo failed
    exit 1
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your help and hints. The main problem was that expanding the alias (like start_ETAP-Cluster) did not work properly. Thus using following in the script did help:

```
shopt -s expand_aliases
source ~/.bash_aliases
```

Using the $Status in my code was misleading, I changed it to $JobID, which reflects better what I wanted. I'm using web hooks in the aliases, which return a JSON Object with the job id. Furthermore assigning $Status=$? works also. Now the code does its work from within the script:

```
$ JobID=$( ${BASH_ALIASES[start_ETAP-Cluster]} 2>/dev/null )
$ echo $JobID
{"JobIds":["8c54392c-363c-4e28-827e-a1384da7fd37"]}
```

Next step will be to move the web hook calls from the aliases to bash functions, will give me more flexibility then aliases.